# Automated static site client page creation with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hugo, static-site

I am looking to build some automated HTML client pages from a template, such as mysite.com/clientpage. The generated page will contain their website url, company name and a portfolio of their products which feeds from a unique JSON file they send to our server. The client page template I use is built in Bootstrap 4 and uses Angular 1 to output the client products from their JSON feed. We just change some of the fields in the template and the page is then renamed with their company name. (eg. mysite.com/clientname.html)

I am struggling to come up with an infrastructure solution that will take their order event data and generate their unique site page, all automated. I have had ideas for generating these sites using SSH(Paramiko) in Lambda doing some SSH tasks on the template, hosting a template on GitHub and editing that every time and then deploying, hosting Wordpress pages etc.

There are a vast array of static site generators such as Hugo, GatsbyJS, Assembly but I am unsure how to tie them into event data for each client order.

The order event data comes in via API Gateway and AWS Lambda, what applications can I use to create these custom pages? How could I create custom client pages from event data?

FLOW

- Customer orders page via website
- Order JSON data passed to AWS Lambda via API Gateway
- Unique customer page is created from a template adding in customers
  website url, company name and the URL of their product feed into the
  HTML page (This page generation part is the part I need automated,
  depending on the details of the customer)

Comment: The page generation would depend on the solution you have used, how you merge the data in JSON to the template, so you need to first choose one and then ask question on specific issue you face with its integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. The pages have to be static (put the data in a DB, and it seems like it would be pretty straight forward web application from there)
2. The Website is hosted on AWS and that is where the static pages should be created.
3. You will handle backing up these static pages in some way unrelated to this solution

You will either use a background process or a request process. It will have more reliable load on your environment if you setup a CRON job to handle the pages creation then if you respond to events. So I would recommend that without know more about your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any templating engine like `ejs` and dump the output into s3.